# How can i map a JsonObject to another JsonObject in java in order to communicate between APIs

Tags: java, json, mapping, integration, api-design

I have an API (A) receiving requests and sending those requests to another API (B). However, before API (A) sends requests to API (B) it needs to format them in the way that API (B) accepts requests. Some of the data received in API (A) will not be used or mapped to the requests sent to API (B), also some of the data fields in API (B) are going to be empty. I want to map the fields from API (A) to a format that (B) accepts.

This is the format that API (A) receives the requests in:

```
{
"customer" : {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "phone" : "000-123-4567",
    "email" : "bob@email.com",
    "zip" : "12345"
    }
}
```

This is the format that API (B) receives requests. This is the format that i want to convert all the requests received by API (A) into before sending them to API (B). This is an example:

```
{
"transaction" : {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "phone" : "000-123-4567",
    "address" : "", 
    "city" : ""
    }
}
```

So the keys that match will be mapped, and the keys that dont match will remain empty. 
The reason I cant change the way API (A) receives requests and match it to the same format as API (B) requests, is because i am going to have it integrated with more than one API. I am not sure if there is an easy way to do this.

So far I have thought about creating a method that will take in a json object (which will be request that A received) and a RequestB object (which i will create and will represent the request to send to API B) compare the keys that match and set the values, then return the correctly formatted request in order to send it to API (B). However, since there will be more than one API that API (A) will be communicating to (multiple formats to convert/map to), this may not be a good solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you need to create models belonging to different `APIs` in your system, you should probably need to look into Java's object mapping frameworks to ease your job, e.g.:

- [Here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappingclasses.html) is a declarative way (Dozer)
- [Here](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) is an imperative way (Model Mapper)

There are a few others as well, you can choose any of these.

Answer (score 0):

In annex to @Darshan_Mehta's answer, I would like to recommend [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org).
Mapper classes can be defined in a minimal & intuitive way with annotations:

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {
    Transaction toTransaction(Customer input);
}
```

The actual implementations are generated at compile time leveraging [Pluggable Annotation Processing API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269).